# Flow id in android (like a thread id)

Tags: java, android

I have many work flow functions. For example:
Flow 1: object1.A() -> object2.B() -> object3.C();
Flow 2: object1.X() -> object2.Y() -> object3.C();
I would like to check that, if C() is call from flow 1 can be exceted now, if from flow2 put it to queue.

Like thread id, but in android they are same original thread id. So how can I get flow id in this case?

Comment: There is no concept called flow in Android or in Java.  If you're using some library that introduces the concept, name and/or tag it.  Otherwise we have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Hi Gabe Sechan, It is like "synchronized" lock in java. But with animation or runnable called in method, lock it is not working, so I must write a custommized queue to synchorize called function everytime animation ends.